# Native lazy load in horizontal scrolling sites (loading="lazy")

Tags: scroll, lazy-loading, horizontal-scrolling

I added the new `loading="lazy"` attribute in a horizontal scrolling gallery site, but the images outside the viewport are always loaded regardless being out of view both in Chrome and Firefox.
My question is, is this new feature only available for vertical scrolling sites? Is there a way to enable it in horizontal scrolling sites?

Comment: Isn't it crazy? Same in Safari. I guess the whole point of lazy loading is that the content is highly likely to be viewed. With horizontal scrollers it's much less likely to be viewed. I think I'm going to solve this with IntersectionObserver and just set the slides to be 'eager' load once I've detected motion.

Comment: It works in Firefox now(111.0.1 (64-bit)). 
Still the same problem in Chrome (Version 111.0.5563.111 (Official Build) (64-bit))